# Why is the edit link greyed out?

Tags: support, editing

I want to edit [Prove an identity about $\iint_S\mathbf{r}\wedge d\mathbf{S}$ using Stokes' theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425651/stokes-theorem-corollary) but the edit link is greyed out and non-functional. What's up?

Update: Someone else edited the post, and now I can, but why was I locked out before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post had a [suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/77477). Since you don't have the edit privilege yet, you have to wait until pending edits are approved or rejected before suggesting another edit.